# FIlter expect output after command execution

Tags: filter, tcl, output, expect

There is a way to filter expect execution, so only a few words are presented to the user? Something similar to execution of a command in shell associated with grep command.

Example: 
I need to execute command "policy show" and filter the results so only lines with word "pri" on second column are shown. Need to hide any lines with word "none".

```
# policy show
Class name                         Policy Type                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/Inbound                           none
 Localhost                         pri(6)
```

Comment: Take a look at the `string match` and `regexp` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is to create a list of the records and use `lsearch -regexp -all` to extract what you need